# Comparing: should I choose Terraform gcp modules or google gcp modules from git

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to serve a landing zone on GCP. I'm looking to get a starting repo and I found that terraform is exposing a foundation github repo with GCP modules while Google are also providing a repo with cloud foundation fast fabric. Which one should I go with, I'm talking in terms of maintenance, good practices, better project stuctures...

Comment: The Google modules sit on top of Terraform. I would use both. You must start with Terraform as the Google modules depend on Terraform. I recommend editing your question to clearly state what you are comparing.

Comment: Clearly, but google modules on google's fast fabric repo are maintained by Google's team, if an update in Terraform they'll certainly update. I. addition it's there product, isn't better to follow their practice to mount a landing zone on GCP

Comment: You are asking for opinions which is off-topic. Where did you get your assumptions about the Terraform and Google development teams? Do not make business decisions based on your guesses. Terraform is developed first then the Google modules. The Terraform Google Provider is the standard, the Google Modules are not.